# Check if an iterator precedes another one

Tags: c++, iterator

I would like to check if an iterator (or similar types) precedes another one. In this example, I would like to check I don't have an infinite loop. It means, "if I apply operator ++ enough times on begin, I arrive to end". Is it possible in C++98 ? Maybe with restriction on the type T ?

```
/**
 * \brief Loop
 * \attention T must implement operator++() and operator!=(const T&)
 * \param begin Begin of the loop
 * \param end End of the loop
 * \pre begin precedes end
 */
template <typename T>
void loop(const T& begin, const T& end)
{
  T run = begin;
  while(run != end)
  {
    /* do something with run */
    ++run;
  }
}

loop(0,10);

std::set<double> x;
x.insert(1.0);
x.insert(2.0);
x.insert(3.0);
loop(x.begin(), x.end());
```

Comment: Shouldn't be possible in general. You could implement an iterator whose  `operator++` behaves like a single step of a Turing machine. Then you ask to solve the halting problem.

Comment: I don't want to impose a specific type of iterator to the user.

Comment: This link explains the requirements and capabilities of each of the iterator concepts.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have random access iterators, such as you would get from a `std::vector`, `std::basic_string`, `std::deque` or `std::array`, and you know they are from the same container, then you can compare them with `operator<` (or any of the other relational operators). Otherwise, you need to document your function's behavior and count on the user to pass valid iterators that meet the criteria.

Comment: It's a good possibility, but I wrote an example with std::set<Type>::iterator because I use it. Actually, I wrote my tool to use it with std::vector and std::set iterator mainly.

Comment: @Caduchon: I don't know what you are trying to say. What do you mean "It's a good possibility"?  *What* is a good possibility?

Comment: The good possibility is to restrict to random access iterators (by a specialisation of the template).

Comment: @Caduchon: I wasn't suggesting that you restrict your function to random access iterators. I was just explaining that you can't do what you are asking *unless* the iterators are random access. The only suggestion I was making was that you clearly document your function.

Comment: @Caduchon: In other words, the simple answer to your question (since you can't assume random access iterators) is no, you can't do that. At least, not with any of the iterators in the standard library.